# Getting Month values for specific year

Tags: sql, oracle

Fisc_prd stands for month
fisc_yr stands for year
I need the result in such a way that if current month is 01(that is Jan) then i need all the period for previous year i.e 1 to 12 and if the current month is not equal to 01 then i need all the period for current year less than current month(e.g if the current month is 3 then i need 1 to 2 as fisc_prd)

I can only get all the fisc_prd for previous year but cant get fisc_prd less than current month for current year. In Below query, CALENDAR table contains all the Month and Year values.By usig this query i can get all the fisc_prd for previous year when current month is 01.

```
SELECT FISC_PRD,FISC_YR FROM CALENDAR WHERE FISC_YR=(SELECT DECODE(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM')),01,(TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY'))-1) ,TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY'))) FROM DUAL)
```

Please share your ideas

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and table DDL. We don't know about your table details, what are the data types. The questions lacks the basic information.

Answer (score 2):

If you're basing this on the current date then you can use a connect-by hierarchical query to get the period and year:

```
select extract(month from add_months(sysdate, 1-level)) as fisc_prd,
  extract(year from add_months(sysdate, 1-level)) as fisc_year
from dual
where level > 1
connect by level <= case when extract(month from sysdate) = 1 then 13
  else extract(month from sysdate) end;
```

Today that gives:

```
  FISC_PRD  FISC_YEAR
---------- ----------
         1       2015
```

To check how it behaves for other dates you can use a modified version that uses a specific date but the same logic; I'm using a bind variable here:

variable dt varchar2;
exec :dt := '2015-01-17';

```
select extract(month from add_months(to_date(:dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1-level)) as fisc_prd,
  extract(year from add_months(to_date(:dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1-level)) as fisc_year
from dual
where level > 1
connect by level <= case
  when extract(month from to_date(:dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) = 1 then 13
    else extract(month from to_date(:dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
end;
```

FISC_PRD  FISC_YEAR

---

```
    12       2014 
    11       2014 
    10       2014 
     9       2014 
     8       2014 
     7       2014 
     6       2014 
     5       2014 
     4       2014 
     3       2014 
     2       2014 
     1       2014
```

Changing the value of `dt` seems to give the result you described; for example with

```
exec :dt := '2015-03-17';
```

you get:

```
  FISC_PRD  FISC_YEAR
---------- ----------
         2       2015 
         1       2015
```

But this is just to test the logic, you can just use sysdate rather than a bind variable.

The `1-level` and using 13 if the current month is January are because you don't want the current month to be included in the result.

Answer (score 2):

This ought to work:

```
with sample_data as (select to_number(to_char(add_months(sysdate, 6 - level), 'mm')) fisc_prd,
                            to_number(to_char(add_months(sysdate, 6 - level), 'yyyy')) fisc_yr
                     from   dual
                     connect by level <= 24)
select fisc_prd,
       fisc_yr
from   sample_data
where  case when to_char(sysdate, 'mm') = '01' then to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')) -1
            else to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy')) end = fisc_yr
and    case when to_char(sysdate, 'mm') = '01' then 13
            else to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'mm')) end > fisc_prd;
```

Answer (score -1):

If your colum "FISC_YR" is datetime datatype then the below query will works for you

```
SELECT FISC_PRD,FISC_YR
FROM CALENDAR

WHERE 
(month(getdate())!=1 AND month(FISC_YR) in(month(getdate())- 1,month(getdate())-2) AND year(getdate())=year(FISC_YR)) 
OR
(month(getdate())=1 AND year(getdate())-1=year(FISC_YR))
```

Comment: NO FISC_YR AND FISC_PRD ARE DECIMAL FIELDS..WHEN I RUN THIS QUERY IT TELLS month is a invalid identifier..

Comment: getdate() is not an Oracle function.